# Probability of the same order

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

Let's consider a set $A$ and another set $B$ where $B \subset T$ . Conside another set $C= T \backslash B$(exclude set B from T). Now, We are given a stochastic process $X(t)$ such that $P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) \leq f(u)$ . $f(u)$ tends to zero faster than $P(X(0) \in  \omega) $ and $P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega) \geq P(X(0) \in \omega )$. How can we prove that 
$$
P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) =o (P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega))
$$
My answer:

since, $f(u)$ tends to zero faster than $P(X(0) \in  \omega)$. so,

$P(X(0) \in  \omega) \geq f(u) \geq P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) $ and $P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega) \geq P(X(0) \in \omega )$. so,

$$
P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega) \geq P(X(0) \in  \omega) \geq f(u) \geq P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) 
$$
which does not seem to prove the result or does it?

Comment: It does, since $$
P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega) \geq P(X(0) \in  \omega) \gg f(u) \geq P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) 
$$ implies $$
P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega) \gg P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) 
$$ which is equivalent to $$
P(X(t)_{t \in C} \in \omega) \in o\left(P(X(t)_{t \in B} \in \omega)\right).$$