# Asymptotic Inequality in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Given that $P(X>a)\leq f(a)$. Now, $f(a)$ tends to zero faster than $P(Y>a)$. Does it mean that $(1)P(X>a) \leq P(Y>a)$ or $(2)P(X>a) \geq P(Y>a)$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $f(a)$ rather than $f(u)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f(a)$ tends form a positive number to zero faster than $P(Y>a)$, then $P(Y>a) \geq f(a)$ will hold in general, because $f(a)$ is generally closer to $0$.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I also thought so but it seems to contradict my another main question. can you please take a look at this question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369620/probability-of-the-same-order

Comment: @user3135030 I think Did answered your question in the comment.

Comment: yes, "DId" did. appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3135030 Where is the contradiction?

Comment: @wythagoras I applied to your answer your quite relevant comment to the question, so to speak. If I should not have, please revert the edit.

Comment: @Did If you are quite sure that it should be $f(a)$ then it is okay. I was not sure at all though, since I don't know very much about probability, maybe $u$ meant something special.

Comment: Nothing that I can think of, but you are right, only the OP knows for sure.

Comment: sorry guys for the confusion, it should be a and not u else it would not make sense to compare the rate of convergence with two independent quantities. @DId : I misunderstood little-o concept. I have got it now. So, no contradiction. Thanks guys. I really did not appreciate these sites but now I am beginning to.